# Gmail Hide Left Panel/Sidebar: Labels, Inbox, Everything!

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a lot of rules that route unread emails to labels. I'd like to not let them distract me when I want to process the Inbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is from this [site](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/20/tutorial/auto-hide-sidebar-gmail.html).

1. Install the "Stylish" Chrome/Firefox plugin
2. Install the "[Gmail autohide sidebar](https://userstyles.org/styles/36980/gmail-autohide-sidebar)" style

Comment: Small note that this style does not work well with the "new" (2018) GMail style. Autohiding the sidebar now exists as a "feature" within GMail: "click on the three horizontal lines in the top left corner and it will hide the left hand side bar" - [source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/wYipP2_iNdM)